# BJT transistor sum

Tags: transistors, bjt, bipolar

[image]

Here I considered it is in active region and considered Vbe=0.6 V.

[image]

I did this:

[image]

I considered it is in active region but it Vce is less than 0.2 V.
What should I do next?

Comment: Your Ib looks good. So does your Ic. (Assuming active mode, of course.) Multiplying Ic by 2.2k gets you a number that is way, way more than the supply rail. So you know that this cannot be in active mode, but must be saturated. (The active mode assumption failed.) That fact changes all your calculations. You now have to assume a small, fixed Vce voltage and completely disregard the active mode beta.

Comment: If you received such a strange result that means that your BJT is in the saturation region. In that case Ic = beta*Ib does not hold anymore. But you can assumeed Vce_{sat} value (0.2V) and additional Ie = Ib + Ic.  Next apply KVL and solve the circuit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've checked your work and provided my own calc results next to yours:

[image]

So I agree with you.

But this only applies when the BJT is in active mode where the assumption of the active-mode \$\beta\$ applies.

Just as you also calculated, the voltage drop across the collector resistor is ***very large***. I agree here, too. The fact that you got a negative value for the collector voltage, when the entire circuit sits between two rails of \$0\:\text{V}\$ and \$10\:\text{V}\$, is all you need to know that the result is nonsense. It's wrong. So the assumption of active mode and \$\beta=50\$ fails.

You know, a priori, that the collector voltage must be between \$0\:\text{V}\$ and \$10\:\text{V}\$. So you need to change your active mode assumptions into saturated mode. Here, \$0\:\text{V} \le V_{_\text{CE}}\le 400\:\text{mV}\$ and the collector now acts like a voltage source, not a current source. So, here you apply two KVL equations:

$$\begin{align*}
10\:\text{V}-2.2\:\text{k}\Omega\cdot I_{_\text{C}}-V_{_\text{CE}}-100\:\Omega\cdot I_{_\text{E}}&=0\:\text{V}
\\\\
10\:\text{V}-10\:\text{k}\Omega\cdot I_{_\text{B}}-V_{_\text{BE}}-100\:\Omega\cdot I_{_\text{E}}&=0\:\text{V}
\end{align*}$$

But you also know that \$I_{_\text{E}}=I_{_\text{C}}+I_{_\text{B}}\$, as that is still true. So:

$$\begin{align*}
10\:\text{V}-2.2\:\text{k}\Omega\cdot I_{_\text{C}}-V_{_\text{CE}}-100\:\Omega\cdot \left(I_{_\text{C}}+I_{_\text{B}}\right)&=0\:\text{V}
\\\\
10\:\text{V}-10\:\text{k}\Omega\cdot I_{_\text{B}}-V_{_\text{BE}}-100\:\Omega\cdot \left(I_{_\text{C}}+I_{_\text{B}}\right)&=0\:\text{V}
\end{align*}$$

That solves out to:

$$\begin{align*}
I_{_\text{C}}&=\frac{10\:\text{k}\Omega\cdot\left(V_{_\text{CC}}-V_{_\text{CE}}\right)+100\:\Omega\cdot\left(V_{_\text{BE}}-V_{_\text{CE}}\right)}{100\:\Omega\cdot 2.2\:\text{k}\Omega+100\:\Omega\cdot 10\:\text{k}\Omega+2.2\:\text{k}\Omega\cdot 10\:\text{k}\Omega}
\\\\
I_{_\text{B}}&=\frac{2.2\:\text{k}\Omega\cdot\left(V_{_\text{CC}}-V_{_\text{BE}}\right)-100\:\Omega\cdot\left(V_{_\text{BE}}-V_{_\text{CE}}\right)}{100\:\Omega\cdot 2.2\:\text{k}\Omega+100\:\Omega\cdot 10\:\text{k}\Omega+2.2\:\text{k}\Omega\cdot 10\:\text{k}\Omega}
\end{align*}$$

Let's assume your figure for \$V_{_\text{BE}}= 600\:\text{mV}\$ and use my own guesstimate of \$V_{_\text{CE}}= 200\:\text{mV}\$. Then we'd find \$I_{_\text{B}}=888.8\overline{8}\:\mu\text{A}\$ and \$I_{_\text{C}}=4.2\overline{2}\:\text{mA}\$. From that, we'd find the saturated mode \$\beta= 4.750\$. Nothing like the \$50\$ that would be the case for active mode.

From the above you can work out that:

$$\begin{align*}
V_{_\text{C}}&=10\:\text{V}-2.2\:\text{k}\Omega\cdot I_{_\text{C}}=711.1\overline{1}\:\text{mV}
\\\\
V_{_\text{B}}&=10\:\text{V}-10\:\text{k}\Omega\cdot I_{_\text{B}}=1.1\overline{1}\:\text{V}
\\\\
V_{_\text{E}}&=100\:\Omega\cdot \left(I_{_\text{C}}+I_{_\text{B}}\right)=511.1\overline{1}\:\text{mV}
\end{align*}$$

And note that \$V_{_\text{C}}\lt V_{_\text{B}}\$. So the base-collector junction is forward-biased, now.

That's the saturated BJT solution, required as the active mode solution was falsified.

Here's an LTspice run:

[image]

The BJT here was tweaked to get close to the earlier assumptions, but not perfectly. So here in practice they work out to \$V_{_\text{BE}}=602.611\:\text{mV}\$ and \$V_{_{\text{CE}_\text{SAT}}}=202.033\:\text{mV}\$. Plugging these actual results into the formulas above, we'd then have found \$I_{_\text{C}}=4.22135\:\text{mA}\$, \$I_{_\text{B}}=888.639\:\mu\text{A}\$, \$V_{_\text{C}}=713.032\:\text{mV}\$, \$V_{_\text{B}}=1.11361\:\text{V}\$, and \$V_{_\text{E}}=510.999\:\text{mV}\$. Which is a perfect match against the results of simulation. So the concepts applied earlier for analyzing the saturated case appear validated by simulation.

Comment: Aside from these calculations, I would make a revelation: I have never understood the meaning of this circuit solution often put in the questions here. Why? It is a transistor stage with a true voltage input with high resistance (thanks to the emitter resistor R3);  therefore it should be controlled with a voltage divider. If there were no emitter resistor, then it would be a transistor stage with current input having a low input resistance;  then it could be driven through a base resistor. Here it has a voltage input but we control it through a resistor R1 like a stage with a current input.

Comment: @Circuitfantasist If I am reading you correctly (that you don't understand why it is that this kind of problem is given to students) then I guess my answer is that (1) there are many ways to pose questions that test a student's ability to think though problems and this is one such; and, (2) although unlikely it is possible that a student might later in life actually encounter such a design; and, (3) analyzing this structure (not for DC Q-point but for its sensitivities to variations in device and supply rail) can help explain why it is rarely seen.